# Not getting "this._Graph.Caches" on Sales Order Copy Order Action

Tags: acumatica

On Sales Orders, when I Copy Order Action. My code error out because the line that retrieves "this._Graph.Caches[BqlCommand.GetItemType(selectorInventoryID)];" is = 0.
The program works fine except on the Action mentioned before.

```
private Type selectorOrderNbr;
private Type selectorInventoryID;

public ItemDiscountClassAttribute() : base(typeof(ARDiscount.discountID))
{}
protected virtual IEnumerable GetRecords()
{
 this.selectorOrderNbr = typeof(SOOrder.orderNbr);
 var cache1 = this._Graph.Caches[BqlCommand.GetItemType(selectorOrderNbr)];             
 var order = (SOOrder)cache1.Current;

 this.selectorInventoryID = typeof(SOLine.inventoryID);
 var cache2 = this._Graph.Caches[BqlCommand.GetItemType(selectorInventoryID)];
 var line = (SOLine)cache2.Current;
```

should be:     cache2 = "{PXCache(1)}"

but output is: cache2 = "{PXCache(0)}"

[Highlighted section where var cache2 is 0 and var line is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxAYK.png)
[image: Code. Highlighted section where var cache2 is 0 and var line is null]

Comment: Can you please specify the exact graph and method where from you have copied this piece of code?

Comment: Samvel, the graph is an extension to SOOrderEntry. The code is custom and I just added a picture with the full code.

Comment: The problem that I see with this code is that it's missing almost all null checkings. If I understand correctly how Acumatica is with Selectors then this code will be called even before you have inserted a line to Sales Order.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through your code, it looks to show the discount applied based on the SOLine. Maybe the issue is discount code is applied before the InventoryID is set on the SOLine? If you update the search for the line to be based on LineNbr, you still may have an empty InventoryID. Maybe returning all discounts when no InventoryID is found may get through the copy operation? If this is the issue, you could reproduce the behavior by selecting a new line, skipping the item, and selecting the discount code first.